# Python нужна помощь с циклом

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Почему данный цикл не печатает строчку 'aga!'  ?

```
x = 1
s = 0
while x:
    s += 1
    if s % 2 == 0:
        print 'continue'
        print s
        continue

    if s == 2:
        print 'aga!'
        continue

    if s > 10:
        print (s + 0.5)
        break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно же включить отладчик и посмотреть, что происходит.

Comment: спасибо большое попробую, но в принцыпе я понял))

Answer (score 2):

Ну потому что перед этим уходит на следующую итерацию:

```
if s % 2 == 0:
    print 'continue'
    print s
    continue
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло (только наверно имеется ввиду ПОСЛЕ этого уходитна следующую итерацию...)

Comment: Нет, не имеется. Перед тем как проверить, что s равно 2 и напечатать "aga!", код уже перескочил на следующую итерацию в предыдущем блоке if.